# Android emulated smartphone device not showing "more" menu items

Tags: android, menu, android-emulator, android-activity, android-actionbar

My Android app (Api level 12, Android 3.1) has an activity with many menu items. Some items are on the action bar (showAsAction="always") while other ones are normal menu items (showAsAction="never") including a submenu: normal menu items have never to be displayed on the action bar, yet they are more than 6 in number so the "more" button also appears when I tap the menu button.

I tested the app on various virtual devices in the emulator and I see that the menu is correctly displayed on all devices  except the smartphone (Android 3.1) where I get the action bar items and, if I tap the menu button,  some of the normal items displayed along with the "more" button; but when I tap the "more" button nothing happens and the further menu items are not displayed.

Is this an issue of the emulator or my app will behave similarly on real smartphone devices?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead,

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
android:orderInCategory="1"
```

Lower the `orderInCategory` value, the first the menu item will be displayed.

Comment: Those menu items have never to be displayed on the action bar.

Comment: They are not hidden, they just are not to be in the action bar. The issue is that they are more than 6 so the "more" button appears but nothing happens if I tap on it (i.e. the further items do not appear) so I can choose just 5 items (plus the ones in the action bar).

Comment: Then, use an Alert Dialog on 6th item and add your other items in that.  You will need to add `CharSequence[]` items to Alert Dialog.

Comment: There's no need to introduce AlertDialog because it is enough to create submenus (so to have max 6 main items) to get what you are talking about.